# How I can convert string to raw string via macros?

Tags: rust

I have a line example `"one two free"` and I need programatically to convert this to `r#"one two free"#` via macros, is this possible?

```
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! fmt_wrap {
    ($msg:block) => {

    }
}

fn main() {
    println!(fmt_wrap!("one two free"));
}
```

Comment: I wonder what could be your usecase

Comment: `"one two free"` and `r#"one two free"#` are literally the same thing.  They're the same string written two different ways.

Comment: I need to convert many strings to raw strings.

Comment: But *why*.  Raw strings are just another way of writing strings.  As far as I know, there is nothing in the language that cares whether you're using raw strings or non-raw strings.

Comment: One difference it is raw string contain data that have unparsed cpecify symbols example (") form .

Comment: But so can regular strings, you just need to escape them.  And there's no point in "converting" a regular string into a raw string, because the regular string won't let you *write* those special characters without escaping.

Comment: If we haven't convinced you there's no reason to do this, I think you need to show what it is you're trying to do, and why you believe converting to raw strings would work.

Comment: @DK - what about the use case where you receive a regex as an input and don't want the user to enter escape slashes all over the place?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**You can't.**

The reason is quite simple: macros by example (the things you declare with `macro_rules!`) **work on a token stream, not a stream of characters**. The input to a macro invocation has to be a valid token stream. This means that the compiler has to tokenize the code before expanding any macros. But the difference between normal string literals `"foo"` and raw string literals `r#"foo"#` is only during tokenization! A string literal is one token.

This means that this:

```
fmt_wrap!("foo " bar");
```

Will never work. Before expanding `fmt_wrap`, the compiler has to convert its input into a valid token stream. But that's not possible!